# Celery + Django REST API + Redis: Trying to offload POST requests to Celery

Tags: python, django, rest, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to offload POST request calls to our API to Celery, as we're going to be sending up to 10 requests per second to our API soon, each of which will have over 100 objects to create in our DB. I figured I'd add them to a queue and let Redis + Celery handle that then work from there.

I'm running into a few issues though.

First, my celery settings:

```
########## CELERY
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

INSTALLED_APPS += ['expert.taskapp.celery.CeleryConfig']
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'pickle']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'

BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'

CELERY_BROKER_URL = env('CELERY_BROKER_URL', default='redis://127.0.0.1:6379')
if CELERY_BROKER_URL == 'django://':
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://'
else:
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = CELERY_BROKER_URL

########## END CELERY
```

Using class basec views for my Django REST Framework, this is my view so far:

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.decorators import task
from .tasks import create


class DataCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        create.delay(request)
```

So the idea is to let the create view handle everythng up until I get to the create portion of the process, where I immediately offload the create task to Celery.

In my tasks.py file I then have this:

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.decorators import task

from expert.models import Chamber, Parameter, Sensor, Data


@task(name='POST request Data point.')
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    queryset = DataCreateSerializer.setup_eager_loading(queryset)
    # serializer_class = DataCreateSerializer

    try:
        sensor = Sensor.objects.get(serial_number=request.data["data_source"])
        request.data["data_source"] = sensor.id
    except Sensor.DoesNotExist:
        print("Sensor serial number " + str(request.data["data_source"]) + " not registered.")
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    dataDict = dict(request.data)
    for param in dataDict['parameters']:
        Parameter.objects.get_or_create(parameter_name=param, parameter_position="None")

    final_data = []
    for data in dataDict['data_array']:
        zipped = zip(dataDict['parameters'], data['values'])
        for parameter, value in zipped:
            # parameter = Parameter.objects.get_or_create(parameter_name=parameter, parameter_position="None")[0]
            parameter = Parameter.objects.get(parameter_name=parameter)
            final_data.append({
                "sensor": sensor.id,
                "parameter": parameter.id,
                "time": data['time'],
                "parameter_value": value
            })
    serializer = DataCreateSerializer(data=final_data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Where I take in the large request, modify it a bit to fit our schema, then do the DB writing stuff.

Now, this all works if I just take that very same "create" function and leave it straight on the CreateAPIView.

When I try to do it with Celery, I get the task showing in my task list when I initialize the celery workers, but I can't manage to get the request to reach celery. I breaks before then with the following error:

```
File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in post
  192.         return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/luke/Projects/expert/impedans_expert/impedans_expert/expert/api/views.py" in create
  249.         create.delay(request)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/task.py" in delay
  461.         return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/task.py" in apply_async
  573.             **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/base.py" in send_task
  354.                 reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py" in publish_task
  310.             **kwargs

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py" in publish
  165.             compression, headers)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py" in _prepare
  241.              body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in dumps
  164.             payload = encoder(data)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py" in __exit__
  77.                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in _reraise_errors
  59.         reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/five.py" in reraise
  131.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in _reraise_errors
  55.         yield

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in dumps
  164.             payload = encoder(data)

File "/home/luke/.virtualenvs/expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in pickle_dumps
  356.         return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)

Exception Type: EncodeError at /expert/api/data/create/
Exception Value: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

I honestly have to clue how to go from there. I've tried googling the exception but even though I saw one page where stuff looked similar-ish, I couldn't make sense of the thread.

I would greatly appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: how did you manage to solve this?` kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type Request is not JSON serializable` :D

Answer (score 3):

Function-based celery tasks require that the arguments passed to it are serializable. You're getting an error that's implying that there's some argument that is not serializable.

First you need to fix your `create` function signature, as it should not have `self` as an argument:

```
@task(name='POST request Data point.')
def create(request):
...
```

Let me know if that works, as I'm looking into a similar solution.

Comment: I've since solved that particular problem. Don't quite remember what I did though. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score -2):

It's hard to tell without being able to debug, but in any case I would start by changing DataCreateAPIView.create to another name, since it may cause conflicts with the method of the same name in tasks.py